# Let the sequence be defined recursively $X_{n+1}=pX_{n}+q$ for p nonzero and $X_{1}$ arbitrary. In what conditions does the sequence converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

Let the sequence be defined recursively $X_{n+1}=pX_{n}+q$ for p nonzero and $X_{1}$ arbitrary. In what conditions does the sequence converge?

I bumped into this problem and I don't know where to even begin. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [characteristic polynomials](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial) ([here is an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559687/show-that-the-sequence-a-1-1-a-2-2-a-n2-a-n1a-n-2-converges-b/2559826#2559826) to avoid it looking dry) perspective
$$X_{n+1}=pX_{n}+q$$
$$X_{n+2}=pX_{n+1}+q$$
thus
$$X_{n+1}-pX_{n}=X_{n+2}-pX_{n+1} \iff X_{n+2}-(p+1)X_{n+1}+pX_{n}=0$$
with characteristic polynomial
$$x^{2}-(p+1)x+p=0$$
with solutions $x_1=1$ and $x_2=p$
and the general term of the sequence
$$X_n=Ax_1^n+Bx_2^n=A+Bp^n$$
We can find $A,B$ from
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
X_1=A+Bp\\ 
pX_1+q=A+Bp^2
\end{matrix}\right.$$
leading to $B=\frac{X_1}{p}+\frac{q}{p(p-1)}$, $A=-\frac{q}{p-1}$ and

$$X_n=-\frac{q}{p-1}+\left(X_1+\frac{q}{p-1}\right)p^{n-1} \tag{*}$$

As a result

- if $|p|>1$ the sequence will diverge
- if $B=0 \iff X_1=-\frac{q}{p-1}$, the sequence is constant.
- if $p=1 \Rightarrow X_n=X_1+(n-1)q$ diverges.
- if $|p|<1$ - converges.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at is an [arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence).

When it converges (notably for $|p|<1$), it converges to the invariant point $\frac{q}{1-p}$.

Actually, if $p=1$, it is just another arithmetic sequence. If $p\neq 1$, the general term is $X_n = p^n(X_0-\frac{q}{1-p}) + \frac{q}{1-p}$ (because $X_n-\frac{q}{1-p}$ is a geometric sequence).

Funnily enough, the limit does not depend on the initial value of the sequence.