# How is it possible to find a closed formula for the $n$-th element of the series defined by $s_{n+1} = \frac{s_n+ax}{1-bx}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

This is the definition of the series ($a,b,x \in \mathbf{R}$):

$$s_{n+1} = \frac{s_n+ax}{1-bx} $$

I would like to find a closed formula, to calculate $s_n$ from $s_0$

How is it possible? The denominator makes it impossible to factor out $s_n$, and I have no idea how to progress further.

Comment: $a$, $b$, and $x$ are constants? If so, would it help you to rewrite this as $s_{n+1} = c s_n + d$ where $c = \frac{1}{1-bx}$ and $d = \frac{ax}{1-bx}$?

Comment: Something similar you will find [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733985/let-the-sequence-be-defined-recursively-x-n1-px-nq-for-p-nonzero-and-x/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140965/recurrence-relation-a-n1-a-nb-a-n-cdot-x/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Written less fancy, you have
$$ s_{n+1}=\alpha s_n+\beta$$
with $\alpha=\frac{1}{1-bx}$ and $\beta=\frac{ax}{1-bx}$.
If we let $t_n=s_n-\gamma$, we find
$$t_{n+1}-\gamma= \alpha t_n+\beta-\alpha\gamma $$
so that if we are lucky and $\gamma=\alpha\gamma-\beta$ (i.e., $\gamma=\frac{\beta}{\alpha-1}=\frac{a}{b}$, at least when no division by $0$ occurs), we have
$$t_{n+1}= \alpha t_n$$
and clearly
$$ t_n=\alpha^nt_0.$$
This gives us
$$ s_n=\alpha^nt_0+\gamma = \alpha^n(s_0-\gamma)+\gamma =\frac{s_0-\frac ab}{(1-bx)^n}+\frac ab.$$
I leave ist to you to check what happens when $bx=1$ or $bx=0$.

Answer (score 0):

By induction easily we can show that
$$s_n = \frac{s_0 + ax + ax\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}(1-bx)^{2^i}}{(1-bx)^{2^{n-1}}}$$
If we simplify the above equation we can get the above equation too.