# Is there any way I can make an explicit formula for the sequance $a_n=x+ya_{n-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Let $a_n$ be a sequence defined by recursion: $a_n=x+ya_{n-1}, a_1=k$. For example, if $(x,y)=(3,5)$, then the sequence would go
$$a=\{k,\space 3+5k,\space 3+5(3+5k),\space ...\}$$
Is there an explicit formula for $a_n$? If not, is there a way to tell if a number is a member of $a$?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733985/let-the-sequence-be-defined-recursively-x-n1-px-nq-for-p-nonzero-and-x) is a related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just another solution.*

Considering
$$a_n=x+y\,a_{n-1}$$ let $a_n=b_n+k$ and replace
$$b_n+k=x +y\ b_{n-1}+k y$$ Let $k=x+k y \implies k=\frac x{1-y}$ (if $y \neq 1$) to make
$$b_n=y \,b_{n-1}$$ which is simple.

Solve for $b_n$ and $a_n=b_n+\frac x{1-y}$

Comment: (+1) I was just about to add an answer very similar.

Comment: @robjohn. In French, we have an expression *"great minds meet"*. The problem is that I am not ! Cheers and thanks.

Comment: Silly question: why does $k=x+ky$?

Comment: @CatPerson. Just to make the constant term equal to zero

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Why can we let k equal what we want?

Comment: @CatPerson. We **solve** for $k$ such that ........

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Let $b_n = a_{n+1}-a_n$. Then $b_n = y b_{n-1}$. Can you finish?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_non-homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients

Comment: If you can finish, please add a complete answer yourself for future visitors