# Finding non-recursive formula from recursive formula $a(n+1) = \frac{a(n) + a(n-1)}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

The first two terms of a sequence are

```
a1 = 2 and 

a2 = 7
```

After that ever term is half of the sum of previous two terms. Thus

```
a3 = (a2 + a1)/2 

a4 = (a3 + a2)/2
```

and so on. How can I find the non-recursive formula for nth term?

Comment: Stock answer is to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial $2t^2-t-1=0$, then choose the constants as to match the initial conditions. If this doesn't make sense, please post (a lot) more context about what you *do* know about recurrences, which you are supposed to use here. Also see [How to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In linear recurrences like this, the first step is to find solutions of the form $a_n = r^n$, ignoring the initial conditions. In this instance, you will find two distinct values of $r$ that work, call them $r_1$ and $r_2$. Then there is a theorem that says that every solution is of the form $a_n = \alpha_1 r_1^n + \alpha_2 r_2^n$ for some constant coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$. The correct coefficients can be found by using the initial conditions.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559687/show-that-the-sequence-a-1-1-a-2-2-a-n2-a-n1a-n-2-converges-b/2559826#2559826

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(a_n+a_{n-1})$$ could be rewritten as $$a_{n+1}-a_n=-\frac{1}{2}(a_n-a_{n-1}),$$

which shows that $\{a_n-a_{n-1}\}$ is a geometric sequence. Thus, $$a_n-a_{n-1}=(a_2-a_1)\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2}=5 \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-2},$$where $n=2,3,\cdots.$

It follows that

$$\sum_{k=2}^n \left(a_k-a_{k-1}\right)=\sum_{k=2}^n \left[5 \cdot \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-2}\right],$$

namely, $$a_n-a_1=5\sum_{k=2}^n\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-2}. $$ As a result, $$a_n=5\sum_{k=2}^n\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-2}+a_1=\frac{20}{3}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+\frac{16}{3},$$ which also holds for $n=1.$

Comment: This is really nice. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I give you a hint, observe that we can write $(a_n,a_{n-1}) = A(a_{n-1},a_{n-2})$ with A a 2x2 matrix.

Now $(a_n,a_{n-1}) = A^{n-1} \times (a_1,a_0)$. So we change the problem of finding a recursive formula to elevate a matrix n-1 times. To do the last, you can study the eignvalues of $A$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. First row of A is 1/2, 1/2 and second row is 1, 0

Comment: I got eigenvalues as -1/2, 1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a_n=a^n$ implies $$ a^{n+1} = \frac {a^n +a^{n-1}}{2}$$
 We solve the equation  $$ a^2 = \frac {a +1}{2}$$ or $$2a^2-a-1 =0$$

After solving for $a$ and finding two values $x_1$ and $x_2$ the general form of solution is$$ a_n = Ax_1^n + Bx_2 ^n$$ where $A$ and $B$ are found from the initial conditions.

Comment: @Dave You are correct. That was very bad mistake. I edited my solution

Comment: Thanks to all of you. With your help I could solve the problem. I got a(n) = (20/3) (-1/2)^n + (16/3)

Comment: Are we allowed to start from a^(n+1) = [a^n + a^(n-1)]/2 ? Using the suggestion by Alex.B I found the eigenvalues of the transformation matrix and found them to be (-1/2) and 1. Then I put x1 = -1/2 and x2 = 1 in the answer provided by Mohammad Riazi-Kermani and determined the constants A and B from initial conditions. Is this approach correct?

Comment: One you found the eignvalues of the matrix you can find A^n (a1,a0) as follows: (a1,a0) = x 1v1 + x2v2 where v1 and v2 are the eignvectors and x1 and x2 the coordinates. Hence A^n (a1,a0) = A^n (x1v1 + x2v2) = x1b1^nv1 + x2b2^nv2, where b1 and b2 are the eignvalues you found.  Finally (an,an-1)= x1b1^nv1 + x2b2^nv2. Then you have an.

Comment: Another option is calculate A^n, A^n = PD^nP^-1, where D is the diagonal matrix and P the change of coordinates matrix. This approach is completely equivalent to that given by  the other users. ( At least I believe this)

Comment: Observe that even what I suggest could be a proof of the procedure described by Mostafa

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic equation is $$2u^2=u+1$$whose roots are $1,-\dfrac{1}{2}$therefore $$a_n=A+B\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$$from $a_1=2$ and $a_2=7$ we obtain$$a_n=-\dfrac{4}{3}+\dfrac{20}{3}\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$$