# Limit of Sequence $x_n = (x_{n-1} +x_{n-2})/2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I was unable to solve this particular question in my real analysis assignment and I am looking for help here.

> Question: Let $x_1 =0$ and $x_2 =1$ and for n>2 define $x_n = (x_{n-1} +x_{n-2})/2$. Then which of following are true?

A ${x_n}$ is monotone

B ${x_n}$ is Cauchy

C Lim $n \to \infty $  $x_n=2/3$.

I was unable to prove $x_n$ is Cauchy and monotone. All I could prove was that $|x_{n+1} -x_n|$=$ 1/(2)^{n-2}$  and I put n tends to infinity in recurrence relation to get limit but I am only getting that x=2x/2 .

I am unable to prove/ doisprove any of the options.

Can you please help?

Comment: Have you tried induction on $n$ to show that $\{x_{n}\}$ is monotone decreasing?

Comment: One more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007188/how-to-prove-that-the-sequence-defined-by-a-1-0-a-2-1-a-n-fraca-n-1a?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+x_{n-1})
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad 
x_{n+1}-x_n=-\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}-x_{n-1})=\cdots 
=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}(x_2-x_1)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}.
$$
and
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+x_{n-1})
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad 
x_{n+1}+\frac{x_n}{2}=x_n+\frac{x_{n-1}}{2}=\cdots=x_2+\frac{x_1}{2}=1
$$
Subtracting the above we obtain
$$
x_n=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{3\cdot 2^{n-1}}\to \frac{2}{3}
$$

Comment: Nicely done - very clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an explicit formula for $x_n$: write characteristic equation$$ 2x^2-x-1=0$$ It solutions are $1$ and $-1/2$ so it is of form $$x_n = a+b({-1\over 2})^n$$ where you can find $a$ and $b$ from initial conditions. Clearly it is convergent with $a$ as a limit and it is not monotone.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$, and $x_3=\frac12$, it is clear that $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not monotonic.

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, you have$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+2}\\x_{n+1}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1}\\x_n\end{bmatrix}$$
and therefore$$\begin{bmatrix}x_{n+1}\\x_n\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$But then, since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\begin{bmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}^n=\begin{bmatrix}\frac23&\frac13\\\frac23&\frac13\end{bmatrix},$$and since$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac23&\frac13\\\frac23&\frac13\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac23\\\frac23\end{bmatrix},$$the limit of your sequence is indeed $\frac23$. And, since the sequence converges, it is a Cauchy sequence.